# Does the HeroLab license let you share your portfolios and custom data files?

Tags: tools, publishing, intellectual-property, hero-lab

Since we're building a Pathfinder RPG setting at bySwarm, I'd like to create custom data files  in HeroLab for our new reaces, feats, etc. I am also creating a portfolio of sheets for NPCs in it. Is there anything in the license that prevents you from sharing these things as HeroLab files on your website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you are encouraged to share your creations.  The Pathfinder d20 SRD has [a bunch of Hero Lab files posted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-creations/hero-lab) that are discussed/developed prominently on the Lone Wolf boards.